# Slackware 14.0 upgrade OpenGL

Tags: upgrade, slackware, opengl

I wanted to run a tutorial program for OpenGL in my Slackware 14.0. It compiled well, but when I try to run it, it quits with an error:

error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.00 ES, 1.10, and 1.20

I am using radeon driver. How to upgrade OpenGL?

Comment: I rather think the version might too high. Where is the tutorial from?

Comment: Here: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/. But I got the answer and it seems to be hard to make it work: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/slackware-14-0-upgrade-opengl-4175438335/

Answer (score 2):

In the latest Mesa release, Mesa 9.0, the Radeon driver supports only GLSL 1.20. Upgrading the driver won't fix your problem.

You need to replace the opensource Radeon driver with the proprietary one, which should support the highest GLSL version that the hardware is capable of.

Comment: Oh. My video card is too old: Radeon 9600 and is not supported by the proprietary drivers any more. I'll have to wait until the open source will support the new functions.